# Setting HBase Region Server Heap Size Through Cloudera Manager

Tags: java, hbase, heap-memory, cloudera-manager

I am using cloudera version 5.5.2. I have been trying to set the region server max heap size in [cloudera manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmynz.png) but irrespective of what value I set it to I always see it as 1.7 GB on the [hbase region server UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHjnJ.png) and jconsole.

I have even tried setting it through hbase region server opts as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHg8T.png) but that fails to start the jvm. The error stats "Invalid max heap size".

What could be going wrong?

**Update 1** :

Updating HBASE_HEAPSIZE to the desired heap size works but that updates the heap size for both the hbase master and the region server. What could be the setting to update just the region server heap size?
Thanks!